# FindAll conditions with different relevance

Tags: c#

About the homework:
There are casters(witch(0)/fairy(1)) and they have spellpower(int). I stored them in a list.

I'm to find the best of both types. (There can be multiple casters with the same spellpower)
I've come up with this code, but there is a problem. If the caster with the most spellpower is a 1, then the first FindAll won't return anything, because it tries to find the caster with type 0 AND with the most spellpower. How can I get a list containing type 0 caster(s) with the most spellpower, if the caster with the most overall spellpower is type 1?

```
private List<Caster> BestCasters()
    {
        List<Caster> temp = new List<Caster>();
        temp = casters.FindAll(x => x.SpellPower == casters.Max(y => y.SpellPower) && (x.TypeOfCaster == 0));
        temp.AddRange(casters.FindAll(x => x.SpellPower == casters.Max(y => y.SpellPower) && (x.TypeOfCaster == 1))); 
        temp.OrderBy(x => x.TypeOfCaster).ThenBy(y => y.CasterName);
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ `GroupBy` behavior is perfect for this:

```
var strongest_casters = casters.GroupBy(c => c.TypeOfCaster)
                               .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.SpellPower)
                                                 .First()
                                      );
```

Or to return more than one of each type:

```
var strongest_casters = casters.GroupBy(c => c.TypeOfCaster)
                               .SelectMany(grp => grp.Where(y.SpellPower == grp.Max(x => x.SpellPower))
                                          );
```

Comment: @NDJ: Thanks.  I try to go all-out with LINQ, when I choose to use it.  Although I often find the code is more readable with explicit loops (and then I won't use any LINQ at all).

Comment: At first it barely looked like C#, but after reading an article about GroupBy, I understand what you're doing there, and your solution is just amazing. I really like it.

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<Caster> BestCasters()
{
    var witches = casters.Where(x => x.TypeOfCaster == 0).ToList();
    var fairies = casters.Where(x => x.TypeOfCaster == 1).ToList();

    int witchesMax = witches.Max(x => x.SpellPower);
    int fairiesMax = fairies.Max(x => x.SpellPower);

    var temp = witches.Where(x => x.SpellPower == witchesMax).ToList();
    temp.AddRange(fairies.Where(x => x.SpellPower == fairiesMax)); 

    return temp.OrderBy(x => x.TypeOfCaster).ThenBy(y => y.CasterName).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. Didn't know about the existence of the Where method.

Comment: BTW, `ToList` is completely useless in the first two lines.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not. Without these `ToList()` whole `casters` list would be iterated 4 times.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you cut the number of iterations of the complete list in half, at the expense of (multiple) memory allocation and copying.  Not sure that's a win.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use FindAll like this you should invoke the Max on a subset only containing the casters of the right kind. Of course it would make more sense to split the initial list first and then fetch the strongest caster of each kind.
Since you did not tell what exactly you have to do I can only hope that you are allowed to split :-)